# I have servlet-api 2.5 provided, but want to use it during integration tests. Is this possible?

Tags: maven-2, integration-testing, jersey

I am using the Jersey Test Framework, that includes servlet-api 2.5 in the test scope.  Unfortunately, I have also written my own custom filter that requires me to have access to servlet-api at compile time.  I don't want to elevate the scope to "compile" though, because I still don't want it in the war file.  Is there any hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to just work. To quote the reference:

> This is much like compile, but
>   indicates you expect the JDK or a
>   container to provide the dependency at
>   runtime. For example, when building a
>   web application for the Java
>   Enterprise Edition, you would set the
>   dependency on the Servlet API and
>   related Java EE APIs to scope provided
>   because the web container provides
>   those classes. This scope is only
>   available on the compilation and test
>   classpath, and is not transitive.

Maven downloads the thing, adds it to test and compile classpaths, but does not include it in packaging.

Comment: OK, so my problem is something else, then.  Thanks.